# jQuery 2.1.0 | Display elements incrementally

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, lazy-loading

I need to display rows of buttons incrementally from top to bottom in a scrollable parent div. These rows of buttons are created using a replace method applied onto a text string converted to html. Since I can have 500+ more rows of buttons to create and display, the text-to-html conversion can take a few seconds or longer, which freezes the UI during conversion. The code below uses a setInterval which unlocks the UI and provides a cool way of "animating" the gradual display of button rows. Problem is, currently, the whole set of rows is repeated at each setInterval, that's not what I want, I can't figure out what to do next. I need each individual row to be displayed incrementally without repeating, from top to bottom, in the order provided by the string, until the length of array is met. The scrolable parent div is a fixed height of 300px. Maybe a Lazy loading method would be better? Any help solving this issue is appreciated.

**[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gp3C/10/)**

```
var placeholder = $('#placeholder');

placeholder.html(placeholdertohtml(placeholder));

function placeholdertohtml(placeholder){

placeholder.html(placeholder.text().replace(/((\d{2},\d{2}))/g, function(match, number){

var blocks = placeholder.text().split(',').length;

console.log(blocks);

var el = number.substr(0,5).split(',');

var prefix = el[0];
var suffix = el[1];

var t = setInterval(function(){
    if (blocks) {  
        var content = '<p><button>'+prefix+'</button><button>'+suffix+'</button></p>';

$('#placeholder').append(content);

        blocks--;

    } else {
        clearInterval(t);
    }

}, 100);

}));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I reworked your code using for loops instead of the replace function to fix the problem.

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/Magzvx)

I basically made a loop that built up an array of html to add:

```
var numberOfPairs = placeholder.text().match(/((\d{2},\d{2}))/g).length;
var countdown = numberOfPairs;
var string = placeholder.text();
var elements = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPairs; i++) {
  var pair = string.substring(5 * i + 1, (5 * i) + 6).split(',');
  var prefix = pair[0];
  var suffix = pair[1];
  elements.push('<p><button>'+prefix+'</button><button>'+suffix+'</button></p>');
}
```

And then looped over the elements with your interval function to get the same "loading" effect:

```
var elementIndex = countdown;
var t = setInterval(function(){
  if (countdown >= 0) {
    $('#placeholder').append(elements[(countdown - elementIndex) * -1]);
    countdown--;
  } else {
  clearInterval(t);
}
}, 100);
```

Comment: Awesome! And no more UI freeze! Thx for input!